# Knock out , toggle visible with button is not working

Tags: knockout.js

I have tried out knockout js for simple toggling of 3 div.
It seems when i toggle the value by checkbox , it is working, but if I update the model value. It simply does not work properly, i have try with if and visible binding.

below is the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/xP579/1/

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you define an observable with the `ko.observable` call it will return a `function`. So when you want to assign a new value to an observable you need to call it as a function with the new value as the argument:

```
self.goDefineForm = function () {
            self.defineParticipant(false);
            self.defineForm(true);
            self.defineOutcome(false);
}
```

A working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/xP579/3/)

You can learn more about [observables from the documentation.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

Comment: @ThanHtetAung Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, [please mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).